# Wikitude object recognition not proper

Tags: android, wikitude

I have being trying to detect a logo with Wikitude SDK. 
Problem is that a single image with even slight color difference is not getting detected.

First  i created an image (That is my logo image) and convert into wtc file and put into my project. 
So only that image recognized by the tracker but even same image with silently different background (while or grey white ) or if we take a smaller image then that it cant recognized by the tracker.
Why this is happen ? and What is the solution of this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the reply to your other thread at the Wikitude Developer board (http://developer.wikitude.com/developer-forum/-/message_boards/view_message/420521), 
I kindly ask you to post the target and test images used so I can check them and assist with your issue.

Regards,
Nicolas